# Cannot use arcgis package in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, arcgis

I cannot use arcgis package in *Jupyter notebook* in browser.
[I created a virtual environment in Conda, **myenv38**:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jrgA.png)

I used `Conda install` to install *arcgis* package, so it is in the virtual environment.
However, when I launch Jupyter Notebook from this environment, [and select **myenv38** as a kernel, *arcgis* returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcgis'`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbbot.png)

When I use `import sys` `sys.executable` in the *iPynb* file of the question, it shows a different path (`'/Users/myname/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python'`). This is apparently weird because the virtual environment is configured with *python 3.8* to make it compatible with the *arcgis*.

This doesn't happen in VScode, but I can't use it because the map doesn't show in it.

Do you have any suggestions?